# Ubuntu Error 2002 “Can't connect to local MySql server through socket…”

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I am trying to access MySql on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (lucid) system. I am aware that there are a lot of results out there for this error but none seem to be helping me. I am a novice on Linux so any help might need to be spelt out.

When running

```
mysql -u root -p
```

at the command prompt, I receive the error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)
```

The sock file definitely exists; running

```
sudo ls -la /var/lib/mysql
```

includes the line

```
-rwxrwxr-- 1 mysql mysql 0 2011-11-03 19.05 mysql.sock
```

and running ls on the parent directory looks like this

```
sudo ls -la /var/lib
drwxr-xr-- 5 mysql mysql 4096 2011-11-03 18.14 mysql
```

I think MySql is running;

```
sudo service mysql start
```

results in

```
mysql start/running
```

And the my.cnf file (located at /etc/mysql/) includes the line

```
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

under the [mysqld] section.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. This site is live and since it is hosting a WordPress installation, not being able to access MySql completely breaks the site!

EDIT

Output from comment;

```
ps -ef | grep mysql
mysql     1869     1  0 20:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
pete      1953  1713  0 20:36 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Comment: what does the output of `ps -ef | grep mysql` show ?

Comment: See the edit for the output

Comment: 754 is a very odd mode to see for the /var/lib/mysql directory.

Answer (score 2):

mysql.sock is NOT a socket file, it is a standard file with 0 byte size.

I'd (1) terminate mysql, (2) delete the mysql.sock file, and then (3)restart mysql which will properly make the socket file.  You should see a socket file looking like the following when doing an ls -l mysql.sock.

```
 srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql            0 2011-10-06 15:25 mysql.sock
```

Comment: Ok, I've deleted it using sudo rm mysql.sock. Now doing ls -l mysql.sock does result in what you've posted however I still get exactly the same error as before.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are getting some type of file permission problem indicated by error 13.  So I'd start investigating that as well.

Comment: I'm really not sure how I would go about investigating that. Any starting points?

Comment: I have run CHOWN -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql I don't know if this should allow mysql all it requires?

Answer (score 0):

mysqld should have its socket file somewhere under `/var/run`. On my debian  system it's `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

`/var/lib/mysql` is the directory for the actual database, not runtime information.